# Montar uma consulta sql filtrando dados

Tags: sql

Estou tentando montar um relatório, onde preciso listar documentos excluídos, tenho a seguinte instrução sql:

```
SELECT id,nf,status,data FROM documentos
```

Por exemplo tenho os seguintes resultados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando listo os excluidos ele me dá o seguinte resultado:

```
 SELECT id,nf,status,data FROM documentos WHERE status LIKE ('%EXCLUIDO%')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém não devo considerar o documento cujo nf é 000002, pois ela foi relacionada em seguida, entao ela não pode aparecer no resultado sql, deveria mostrar só a nf 000001.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: E o que é já foi `relacionada`? Poderia nos dar exemplos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o not exists para verificar as NF que estão com mais de um status.

```
SELECT id,nf,status,data 
FROM documentos d1
WHERE status LIKE ('%EXCLUIDO%')
and not exists (SELECT 1 FROM documentos d2 
                         where d1.nf = d2.nf 
                         and d2.status <> d1.status)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,nf,status,data FROM documentos WHERE status = 'EXCLUIDO' and NF <> '000002'
```

Coloquei o status com o sinal de `=` pois a query fica mais leve sem a utilização do like.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa filtrar os itens com *status "EXCLUIDO"* (como já está fazendo) e também com *nf* diferente de *"000002"*:

```
SELECT id, nf, status, data 
FROM documentos 
WHERE status LIKE ('%EXCLUIDO%') 
  and nf <> '000002'
```

**editado após comentário**

No caso da lista de *nf* não válida, a consulta precisaria ser alterada para usar o `NOT IN` conforme abaixo:

```
SELECT id, nf, status, data 
FROM documentos 
WHERE status LIKE ('%EXCLUIDO%') 
  nf NOT IN ('000002', '000003', '000003')
```

Comment: e se no caso tiver várias nf ? como aplicaria essa condição que você fez? no and nf <> '000002'

Comment: @GustavoRibeiro, alterei a resposta

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, nf, status, data 
FROM documentos 
WHERE status = EXCLUIDO' 
  and nf not in ('000002')
```

Como seu campo `status` sempre vai ser *"EXCLUIDO"*, quando não for para ser exibido, fazer uma comparação de igualdade, ao invés de um `like` no `where` vai fazer com que a sua busca seja mais performática.

Na restrição de `nf` você pode ir adicionando as `nf` de acordo com sua necessidade, por exemplo: `nf not in ('000002','000003','000004')`, porém acredito que com o tempo serão adicionadas novas `nf` nessa clausula, com isso seria melhor ter algum tipo de campo ou até uma outra tabela referenciando essas `nf`, para não deixa-las fica na sua consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi direito, acho que com o Except já conseguiria resolver seu problema:

```
create table #ttt1 (
    id int
    ,nf int
    ,status varchar(50)
    ,data datetime
)

insert into #ttt1 values
(1,1,'excluido',getdate()),
(2,2,'excluido',getdate()),
(3,2,'relacionado',getdate()+1)

select nf from #ttt1 t1 where status = 'excluido'
except
select nf from #ttt1 t1 where status = 'relacionado'
```

Vai retornar somente as NF que não tem relacionado

Answer (score 0):

**Tabela utilizada**

[image: consulta]

**SQL**

```
SELECT id,nf,status,data, count(NF) as c FROM documentos group by NF having c = 1
```

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> O mesmo resultado se obtém com a consulta abaixo

`SELECT id,nf,status,data FROM documentos group by NF having count(NF) = 1`

[image: outra consulta]

[**cláusula HAVING**](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184262(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score -2):

SELECT id,nf,status,data FROM documentos
WHERE STATUS ='EXCLUIDO'

Comment: Um pouco mais de atenção. Leia atentamente o problema dele.